# How can I get the time execution of the code?

Tags: python, time, generator

So i want to get the time execution. Need it to make condition that checks that execution time of code. If the seconds get more than 5 then it goes to next lines of code. Working on passwords creator that makes passwords that ends/starts with specified symbols in string. So, if I will get "freeze" of printing when the print function will not print anything because of none solutions then i need that time execution.

```
while True:
    sample = random.sample(string, lenght)
    x = ''
    if x in passwords:
        continue
    else:
        if starts["enabled"] == True or ends['enabled'] == True:
            counter += 1
            x = ''.join(sample)
            if starts['enabled'] == True and ends['enabled'] == True:
                if x.startswith(starts['startWith']) and x.endswith(ends['endWith']):
                    if x in passwords:
                        continue
                    else:
    
                        print(f"# {counter}. {x}")
                        passwords.append(x)
            if starts['enabled'] == False and ends['enabled'] == False:
                if x in passwords:
                        continue
                else:
                    print(f"# {counter}. {x}")
                    passwords.append(x)
            if starts['enabled'] == True and ends['enabled'] == False:
                if x.startswith(starts['startWith']):
                    if x in passwords:
                        continue
                    else:
                        print(f"# {counter}. {x}")
                        passwords.append(x)
            if starts['enabled'] == False and ends['enabled'] == True:
                if x.endswith(ends['endWith']):
                    if x in passwords:
                        continue
                    else:
                        print(f"# {counter}. {x}")
                        passwords.append(x)
        else:
            counter += 1
            x = ''.join(sample)
            print(f"# {counter}. {x}")
    if timeit.timeit('print(f"# {counter}. {x}")', number=1) >= 5:
        print("Thats all..")
        pass
    if len(passwords) == len_pass or len(passwords) <= len_pass:
        if len(passwords) == len(string) ** lenght:
            print("\n")
            print(f"{passwords}\n")
            break
        if len(passwords) == len_pass:
            print("\n")
            print(f"{passwords}\n")
            break
```

Comment: To get the time execution of the code I recommend you using the perf_counter function from the time module.

Comment: I used it with condition but not working. Used 
t1 = perf_counter()
[...]
t2 = perf_counter
a = t1-t2

if a >= 5:
    ...
    pass

Comment: You should type t2-t1 not the countrary

Comment: I have done as you said and still not working. https://onlinegdb.com/HdN58DliR

Comment: Print the value of wynik to see the amount of time

Comment: Well, i know but I need to break loop if the execution time gets more than specified seconds or miliseconds